# mixed with other UIViewAnimations in a block

Tags: ipad, ios, uianimation

I was trying to implement something resembling the iBook store on iPad.
When you tap on a book cover it will flip and scale in one fluid motion, from the book cover to an empty background - which then loads the content.

I have tried different approaches, first flipping, then scaling, I tried wrapping the `transitionFromView` inside the `animateWithDuration` block, but i can't get it to look properly. It will either do one then the other, or in the last case do one, then 'flickr' and do nothing.

```
[UIView transitionFromView:fromView
                    toView:toView
                  duration:0.8
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                    if (finished) {
                            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4
                                animations:^{[fromView setFrame:originFrame];}
                                completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
                    }
                }];
```

Blocks are great for animations, no doubt! 
But how can I both flip and scale at the same time?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to produce this effect using non-block animations by performing the flip on a view containing the views you switch between.

```
CGRect endFrame; //The frame of the view after animation
UIView *sview; //The superview containing the first view
UIView *view1; //The first view, to be removed from sview
UIView *view2; //The second view, to be added to sview

view2.frame = view1.frame;
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.8];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:sview cache:YES];
[view1 removeFromSuperview];
[sview addSubview:view2];
sview.frame = endFrame;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

For this to work, the autosizing mask on view2 must be resizable in width and height.

Comment: I will try it out first thing in the morning:) thanks. I still hope there is a way of doing it with a block.